# how to open Map with routes using the user specified latitude and longitude in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Can u give me code for opening Map using the user specified latitude and longitude in blackberry.I tried with BlackberryMapsDemo im not getting routes displayed so please
help me out.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the maps from code you'll have to use the Invoke API.

Displaying a route can be achieved by using the MapsArguemnts

```
String doc = "<location-document>...</location-document>";
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, new MapsArguments(MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT, doc));
```

[Display and clear a route on a map by using a location document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/CS_determining_a_route_using_getRoute_893347_11.jsp)